# Angular formGroup. The radio button does not activate

Tags: angular, forms, bootstrap-4, angular-material, radio-button

Good morning. I am working with react forms in angular.
I am trying to get two radio button marked based on true / false status in the database.

With the variable viernesOk = true
It works perfectly (the radio button (SI) activated).

```
<div class="col-6">
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" formControlName="viernesOk"  [checked]="form.value.viernesOk === true" value=true>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">SI</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"  formControlName="viernesOk"   [checked]="form.value.viernesOk === false" value=false>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox4">NO</label>
     </div>
```

[image]

The problem is when viernesOk = false.
It does not mark radio button (NO).
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It should work if viernesOk is set. You could try "!== true" instead of "=== false" to deal with "null".

Comment: Thank you. It does not work with "! == true". 
I'm thinking about this: if I set the conditioner to true, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved it, although I am not satisfied.

1.
The variable viernesOk was converted to String:

viernesOk:new FormControl("false"),

2.

I put quotes in value:

**Before**

```
[checked]="form.value.viernesOk=== true "
 value = true
[checked]="form.value.viernesOk=== false "
 value = false
```

**Now**

```
[checked]="form.value.viernesOk=== true "
 value = "true"
[checked]="form.value.viernesOk=== false "
 value = "false"

**Works for angular material:**
<mat-radio-group formControlName="viernesOk">
          <mat-radio-button class="material-radio" value="true"[checked]="form.value.viernesOk === true">SI</mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button class="material-radio" value="false"  [checked]="form.value.viernesOk === false">NO</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
```

**And also bootstrap:**

```
<div class="col-6">

      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input 
        class="form-check-input" 
        type="radio" 
        formControlName="viernesOk"  
        [checked]="form.value.viernesOk === true" 
        value="true">
        <label class="form-check-label">SI</label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input 
      class="form-check-input" 
      type="radio"  
      formControlName="viernesOk"   
      [checked]="form.value.viernesOk === false" 
      value="false">
        <label class="form-check-label">NO</label>
      </div>      
   </div>
```

**Therefore, I am left wondering why the conditional statement reads a boolean as a string? ;[**

Answer (score 0):

Try using form group add it to html

```
    <div class="col-6" [formGroup]="form">
```

In your component

```
form: FormGroup;     
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder){    
      this.form = fb.group({    
        viernesOk:false    
      });   
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. Its correct configuration:             viernesOk: new FormControl (false).                    but it should work.